# Using Multibib with Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex, natbib, multibib

For the defense of my PhD, I have to finish my presentation with a complete list of my publication. In the manuscript, I used the multibib package to generate automatically the list and it works fine. Now when I am using it in Beamer, it get a bit lost but it is understandable as you might see below.

[image: Example on the literature slide]

What I expect from the package was to generate its own slide/title instead of a section and paste the proper bibliography instead of just damping everything on the slide and create some empty section. Again I understand this behaviour, but I want to know if there is a workaround or another way to generate my list of publications.

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[pdf,10pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pub}{{Journal}}
\newcites{confintwith}{International conferences with lecture committee}
\newcites{confint}{International conferences without lecture committee}
\newcites{confnat}{National conference with lecture committee}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary and Perspectives}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{List of publications and conferences}
    \scriptsize
    \nocitepub{Bontemps2013}
    \bibliographystylepub{abbrvnat}
    \bibliographypub{Chapter/Bibliography}

    \nociteconfintwith{Paquet2013, Vanneste2012b, Vanneste2012a, Bao2011c, Vanneste2011a, Bao2011b, Vanneste2010}
    \bibliographystyleconfintwith{abbrvnat}
    \bibliographyconfintwith{Chapter/Bibliography}

    \nociteconfint{Bontemps2011b, Bontemps2011a}
    \bibliographystyleconfint{abbrvnat}
    \bibliographyconfint{Chapter/Bibliography}

    \nociteconfnat{Vanneste2011b}
    \bibliographystyleconfnat{abbrvnat}
    \bibliographyconfnat{Chapter/Bibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would do it manually for two reasons; `beamer`, by design, doesn't like bibs, captions, footnotes etc. AND you have not so many publications so hand tuning them with a visually appealing, color coded theme is much better than trying to bend a bowling bowl with `biblatex+beamer`

Comment: @percusse by doing it manually you means adjusting the font size for each reference. Well I will try it as I am not that satisfied with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial solution to my problem. This is not perfect as I want the citation to be sorted first by years and then by authors which abbrv nat bibliography style won't do. The trick has been just to redefine the \bibsection command. In my case, I choose to put the various category within a block but I assume you can adjust the solution to your requirements using \bibname in the brackets. Here is the code:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{List of publications and conferences I}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{block}{International conferences with lecture committee}
        \nociteconfintwith{Paquet2013, Vanneste2012b, Vanneste2012a, Bao2011c, Vanneste2011a, Bao2011b, Vanneste2010}
        \bibliographystyleconfintwith{unsrtnat}
        \bibliographyconfintwith{Chapter/Bibliography}  
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{List of publications and conferences II}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{block}{Journal}
        \nocitepub{Bontemps2013}
        \bibliographystylepub{abbrvnat}
        \bibliographypub{Chapter/Bibliography}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{International conferences without lecture committee}
        \nociteconfint{Bontemps2011b, Bontemps2011a}
        \bibliographystyleconfint{abbrvnat}
        \bibliographyconfint{Chapter/Bibliography}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{National conference with lecture committee}
        \nociteconfnat{Vanneste2011b}
        \bibliographystyleconfnat{abbrvnat}
        \bibliographyconfnat{Chapter/Bibliography}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

I try to move on biblatex to solve the citation order problem but the package seems not so easy in its use...

Comment: I switch to biblatex to solve the citation order problem. With a few tweaks, it works just fine:
\usepackage[hyperref=true,style=authoryear,sorting=none,minnames=3,maxnames=10,backend=bibtex8,dashed=false,natbib=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}